# Hover issue with background colour Slicknav responsive menu

Tags: css, menu, slicknav

I have an issue using the slicknav responsive menu, if the navigation buttons have a different background colour set for the hover in the stylesheet, if you hover over the actual  tag text the background colour changes correctly, but if you hover over any part of the button away from the text, then the colour behind the actual text doesn't change. So you get a rather ugly box around the text in the original colour. This is happening in all browsers tested.

I cannot find any way to stop this happening, the css file is not that complicated. I've used Slicknav now on a few sites and always had the same problem, but this time I really need to fix it.

You can see an example of this here: http://www.yorkluxuryholidays.co.uk/

In responsive mode, hover anywhere over one of the menu items that have sub menus, but not directly over the menu text itself, and the area behind the text does not change colour.

This is the css I'm using for the hover:

```
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item:hover {
background:#59584e;
color:#fff; }
.slicknav_nav a:hover{
background:#59584e;
color:#fff;}
```

It seems to make no difference which class you set the colour on, either or both, the behaviour is exactly the same.

I'd love to know if there is a way to fix this with the css!

Comment: `.slicknav_item:hover a { background: transparent; }`

Answer (score 0):

Add in your css :

```
.slicknav_nav a:hover * {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#7b9fc7;
}
```